# A gradient system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A system of the type
$$\dot{x} = f(x), \quad f(x) = -\text{grad} V(x),$$
is called a gradient system. Investigate the stability of a fixed point.
I try to compute the Lie derivative of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

For stable, I try to use if $x_0$ is a fixed point of $f$. If there is a Liapunov function L, then $x_0$ is stable.